# Есть ли кнопка «Ответить на комментарий»?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, комментарии

Есть ли возможность в комментариях к вопросам/ответам быстро установить обращение к другому пользователю (имею в виду строчка `@ник пользователя`), который присутствует в этом вопросе (автор вопроса, авторы ответов, комментаторы).

Очень необходимо при участии в комментариях уже 3х пользователей. Вручную набирать `@ник пользователя` лень :)

Если такой возможности нет, то можно ли ее добавить в функционал сайта?

Comment: А разве ее нет? Набираете `@`, далее начинаете набираете ник и появится список. Единственное - автора вопроса или ответа так выделить не получится, т.к. он и так получает оповещение. Где-то про это уже был вопрос на мете

Comment: Хм, на форумах часто рядом с ником автора сообщения стоит значок по нажатию на который в тексте ответа отображается его ник. Так было бы удобнее конечно.

Comment: Опытным путем было только что установлено, что еще после появления списка, есть возможность автозаполнения имени при нажатии TAB. Хотя вариант со значком был бы действительно гораздо удобнее.

Comment: @Visman: получите, распишитесь.

Comment: Поддерживаю, кнопки Ответить на комментарий сильно нехватает. Вполне естественное действие, ручной набор @ник сбивает с толку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А ещё есть userscript, который добавляет кнопочку «ответить».

**Выглядит так:**

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Источник:** https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments

**Код, подправлен для работы с Ru.SO:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           stackoverflow-comment-reply
// @namespace      stackapps
// @description    Add "reply" links to comments
// @version        1.1d
// @match          *://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          *://serverfault.com/*
// @match          *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match          *://superuser.com/*
// @match          *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match          *://stackapps.com/*
// @match          *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match          *://stackexchange.com/*
// @match          *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match          *://askubuntu.com/*
// @match          *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match          *://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match          *://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match          *://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match          *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @author         Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe
// ==/UserScript==

/* MOD: don't run if not SE and user not logged in */
if (!window.StackExchange || window.StackExchange.options.user.isAnonymous )
    return;

// Thanks to Shog9 for this idea for making the script work in both
// Chrome and Firefox:
// http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/46562
function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};

with_jquery(function($) {

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".comments").each(put_reply_links);
        }, 100);
    });

    // event handler for a click on the reply links
    function reply() {
        /* MOD: changed the following 2 lines to detect the new Add Comment link */
        var commentlinkId = $(this).closest(".comments").next().attr("id");
        var commentlink = $('#'+commentlinkId + ' a.js-add-link')[0].click();
        var username = goodify($(this).prev().text().replace(/♦/, ""))
        var formid = commentlinkId.replace(/^.*-(\d+)$/, "add-comment-$1");
        var ta = $("#" + formid + " textarea")[0];
        var start = ta.selectionStart;
        var end = ta.selectionEnd;
        var shift = username.length + 3;
        ta.value = "@" + username + ": " + ta.value;
        ta.focus();
        ta.selectionStart = start + shift;
        ta.selectionEnd = end + shift;
    };

    function put_reply_links() {
        $(this).find(".comment:not(:has(.reply-link)) .comment-user").each(function () {
            /* MOD: // changed click by on(click) */
            $("<span class='reply-link' style='cursor:pointer;opacity:0.3' title='reply'> &crarr;</span>").on('click',reply).insertAfter(this); 
        });
    }

    $(".comments").each(put_reply_links);

    function goodify(s) {
        return s.replace(/ +/g, "");
    }   
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.

Comment: Круто! Надо бы где-то складировать такие знания.

Comment: @VladD: завести метку [meta-tag:лайфхак]?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Например, так :)

Comment: @VladD: а давайте и вправду придумаем способ или хорошую метку.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Метка «лайфхак» не так уж и плохо. Потом кто-нибудь её раскритикует и предложит метку получше, но это неважно, вопросы уже будут сгруппированы. Если их наберётся много, можно будет устроить канонический™ вопросоответ со всеми ссылками.

Comment: @VladD посмотрим, что предложат. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1461/181472